# Fancyhdr's footer at different heights

Tags: spacing, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to make a footer that sits flush with the bottom of the page. Below is what I think is relevant:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=$if(papersize)$$papersize$$else$a4$endif$paper, % Change to a4
    top=3cm, % Top margin
    bottom=0cm, % Bottom margin
    left=2cm, % Left margin
    right=2cm, % Right margin
    includefoot
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
…
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\includegraphics{logo.jpg}}
\rhead{}
\lhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{70pt}    % round to the point
\setlength{\footskip}{54pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-4\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-130pt}

\fancyfoot{}

\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{fplgreen}{HTML}{769A8C}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \vspace{3.5em}
    \centerline{%
        \colorbox{fplgreen}{\parbox[b][0.5cm][t]{\paperwidth}{~}}%
    }
}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
    {\hspace{-0cm}\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{\ssmall Registered Office: Whiting \& Partners, Garland House, Garland Street, Bury St. Edmunds, Suffolk IP33 1EZ\newline
    Registered in England and Wales. Company Registration Number: 000000}}
}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
    \hspace{1cm}\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{%
        \begin{center}
            \scriptsize
            \textcolor{fplgreen}{\textbf{Company Name}}\\
            Address\\
            Adrdess\\
            Address\\
            Address\\
            \textcolor{fplgreen}{\textbf{T:}} Phone\\
            \textcolor{fplgreen}{\textbf{E:}} Email\\
            \textcolor{fplgreen}{\textbf{W:}} Website\\
        \end{center}
    }
}
```

The values I have used for `footskip` and `textheight` are the result of trial and error. The last page of the document looks fine with the footer flush with the bottom edge of the paper. For some reason though, all the other pages sit a little way above the bottom of the page.

I've attached screenshots blurring any company details.

**Last page - correct**
[image: Last Page which lis correct]

**Other Pages - incorrect**
[image: Other pages that are incorrect.]

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your replies.

@Torbjørn T. I looked in the `.log` file and there was indeed a line that said that `\footskip` needed to be at least 53.6 so I made it 54pt. I have updated the code above to reflect that but I am still having the same problem. There are no more warnings in the log file about the header or footer.

@Ulrike Fischer  Why shouldn't I use the centre environment in the footer? I tried removing it and it did not fix the spacing issue.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Look in the `.log` file. `fancyhdr` will write a warning to that file if `\headheight` or `\footskip` is too small, and tell you how large they have to be.

Comment: If you want to keep the company info confidential you should edit your code. Beside this: Better don't use the center environment in the footer.

Comment: You might try \smash on all you parboxes.  I'd test it myself, but your code fragment isn't a full MWE.

Comment: If you want to address a comment, use the @ and then the name of the user that commented. @ in the post does nothing ....